# what does `PS` command mean in vscode terminal on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am trying to reproduce this [post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial).

this is a classic hello world in java, with additional `package app;`

```
package app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

when I click "run" btn inside this code, vscode output this bunch

```
Hello Java
PS C:\Lecture_java\Lecture001\Hello> & 'C:\Users\ubuntu\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.23.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Lecture_java\Lecture001\Hello\bin' 'app.App'
```

first line is the output of my java code.

I guess the second line is the log that how vscode acturally process the java file.

## question

what does `PS` command  mean?

the `PS` command only work inside vscode terminal. running `PS` command in cmd.exe gives this error.

> 'PS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PS indicates it is a powershell prompt.

Powershell code cannot be run inside a command.exe prompt.