# Visual Studio Code , PS(need explanation and how to remove it)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

What is PS?
Just need a clear explanation, don't be so complex. Thank You.
How can I remove it?
C:\Users, instead of PS C:\Users\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does \`PS\` command mean in vscode terminal on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221042/what-does-ps-command-mean-in-vscode-terminal-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

PS denotes that VSCode is using Powershell as default terminal.

To change it:

1. Ctrl + Shift + P (Command Palette)
2. Type: `Terminal: Select default profile` and hit enter
3. Select Command Prompt from the options and that should remove the PS.

Comment: Tqvm this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The PS indicates it is a PowerShell prompt.

Powershell code cannot be run inside a command.exe prompt.

Answer (score 1):

the solution:

```
Ctrl + Shift + P (Command Palette)
Type: Terminal: Select default profile and hit enter
Select Command Prompt from the options and that should remove the PS
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit of context for your answer ?